# Connect Orange 3.20 to postgresql database

Tags: orange, databases

I installed orange 3.20 on windows 7. It works so far, the problem is connecting it to a server-based Postgres database. While the connection can be made at the moment, when you try to load a table the message "missing extension *quantile*" comes up. A few problems are coming up with this message. It seems like it is not possible to install this extension on a windows server without a lot of stress. The extension seems not to be actual (version 2015) and is not compatible with the actual PostgreSQL versions (which will cause trouble for future updates). Does anyone know if Orange will support this in the future and a convenient way to use Orange for windows 7?

Comment: See this answer here: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/39284/we-are-using-postgresql-to-store-big-data-and-are-concerned-it-may-crash-the-on/39395#39395

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To summarize my linked answer. While you may be able to connect Orange to Postgresql, Orange does not handle large datasets very well (it will cause it to crash). Generally, it does not support datasets the size that you would be storing in SQL sized databases. Personally, I think Orange works, and is most effective, with smaller sized datasets for illustrative tasks and exploratory data analysis.

Comment: Thank you for that important hint! Then It seems to be better to skip the idea of using Orange for data analyses. The search for an open source data analyses programm starts again.

Comment: @oppia04 Have you considered using Python?

Comment: not yet, but I will in the near future. Thank you!